# How can select first radio with each()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

select first radion button with `Jquery.each`

is there any option to select first radio from each div

```
<div>
<table class="sortable accountTable float_left">
      <tr>
        <td class="textlmiddle"><input type="radio" value="" rel=
        ".structure_group1" checked='checked' /></td>
        <td>Organisation structure 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="textlmiddle"><input type="radio" value="" rel=
        ".structure_group2" /></td>
        <td>Organisation structure 2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="textlmiddle"><input type="radio" value="" rel=
        ".structure_group3" /></td>

        <td>Organisation structure 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="textlmiddle"><input type="radio" value="" rel=
        ".structure_group4" /></td>
        <td>Organisation structure 4</td>
      </tr>
</table>
 </div>
<div>
<table class="sortable accountTable float_left">
      <tr>
        <td class="textlmiddle"><input type="radio" value="" rel=
        ".structure_group1" checked='checked' /></td>
        <td>Organisation structure 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="textlmiddle"><input type="radio" value="" rel=
        ".structure_group2" /></td>
        <td>Organisation structure 2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="textlmiddle"><input type="radio" value="" rel=
        ".structure_group3" /></td>

        <td>Organisation structure 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="textlmiddle"><input name="acc_number2" type="radio" value="" rel=
        ".structure_group4" /></td>
        <td>Organisation structure 4</td>
      </tr>
</table>
 </div>
<div>
<table class="sortable accountTable float_left">
      <tr>
        <td class="textlmiddle"><input type="radio" value="" rel=
        ".structure_group1" checked='checked' /></td>
        <td>Organisation structure 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="textlmiddle"><input type="radio" value="" rel=
        ".structure_group2" /></td>
        <td>Organisation structure 2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="textlmiddle"><input type="radio" value="" rel=
        ".structure_group3" /></td>

        <td>Organisation structure 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="textlmiddle"><input name="acc_number2" type="radio" value="" rel=
        ".structure_group4" /></td>
        <td>Organisation structure 4</td>
      </tr>
</table>
 </div>
```

​here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ytU3b/)

Comment: `$('input[type="radio"]:first', 'div')`

Comment: I think that'll only find the first radio button, not the first in each div.

Comment: @adeneo actually, that does work - I forgot that this syntax is actually equivalent to `$('div').find('...:first')` which does correctly iterate over each div and _then_ find the `:first` within the second selector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this would work:

```
$('body > div').each(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]', this).first().prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `$('body > div')` and not just `$('div')`

Comment: In the absence of knowledge of the OP's complete page markup, really just to demonstrate that it's best to ensure you only touch the divs you're really interested in, and not any other div that might happen to appear on the page.